# What is the difference between the tags [npm-liveserver] and [nodejs-liveserver]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [npm-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-liveserver) has a wiki at
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/npm-liveserver/info
while the tag [nodejs-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs-liveserver) has no wiki (yet).

My hunch is that these two tags are in fact synonyms of one another.
Not sure if it is important which would be made synonym of which? - But
making [nodejs-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs-liveserver) a synonym of [npm-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-liveserver)
seems more natural to me, if nothing else because the latter has a wiki
while the former does not.

I might add that `npm` is the default package manager of `Node.js`:
"npm is distributed with Node.js- which means that when you download
Node.js, you automatically get npm installed on your computer."
https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

I do not have the reputation (score?) required to make these changes myself.

Comment: Also, `[npm-liveserver]` is shorter than `[nodejs-liveserver]`, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the 15 questions tagged [nodejs-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs-liveserver), 8 of them were already tagged [npm-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-liveserver), so I went ahead and created the synonym:

[nodejs-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs-liveserver) (× 15) → [npm-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-liveserver) (× 58)

The [name of the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) seems to be "live-server" and not "liveserver", and therefore I renamed [npm-liveserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-liveserver) to [npm-live-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm-live-server).

Comment: Thanks! - I needed to write [https://stackoverflow.com/tags/npm-live-server/synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/npm-live-server/synonyms) into the URL of my web browser to remind myself of how to see which tag is a synonym which.